# Права на исполнение

Tags: apache, php, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! Пишу свою CMS. Перешел на ubuntu и столкнулся с проблемой - необходимо через php создавать на хосте файлы типа лог-файлов и кэш-файлов, но прав у php на это нет. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по простому, то может помочь

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R
```

Answer (score 5):

Прав нету не у php а у пользователя запустившего php , по дефолту это пользователь от которого работает ваш веб сервер. Измените владельца директории в которых создаете файлы, на пользователя от которого запускается php. Делается утилитой chown.